# Animate a dialog Fragment from a point of origin Android

Tags: android, android-animation

Good day, I am trying to do an animation with a dialog fragment that emanates a from a point of origin. like described in this android material design guideline [here](http://www.google.com/design/spec/animation/responsive-interaction.html#responsive-interaction-material-response) i tried following the related documentation which says use stateListAnimator but i don't know how to achieve this using object animation. How can i make the animation start from the origin of contact? Just a guideline would be sufficient or pointing me to the right direction. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Please have a look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30122340/3176433

I think this will work for you.