# Point of origin animation android

Tags: java, android, material-design

I am currently doing an animation from the material spec design, now I want to enable to do a point of origin animation which is showed here:

[Sample Animation Link](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/v_2/material_ext_publish/0B0NGgBg38lWWMXpyWDRDWDJpeDA/animation-responsiveinteraction-materialresponse-030202_PointOfOrigin_DO_001.webm)

How can I do that animation of pre lollipop? Is there a way doing it in pre-lollipop devices?

Comment: Have you tried to move the pivot x (0) and pivot y (viewHeight) to the point and then apply scale animation with appropriate interpolator like Overshoot? Have you think of animating view RectF?

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski I was planing to do it in fragment, I have tried a regular scale animation on a view but it always start at the top left going bottom right.

Comment: If you change the pivot x and y with setPivotX and setPivotY to will have different behaviour.

Comment: You have to transform it then to do what you want. For example, the point which is the origin of the animation is actually `y` and `-x` away from the origin of the image. Account for that. **Edit:** that might not be totally right; it might just be that the x-s are the same but you get the point.

Answer (score 2):

I've achieved this point of Origin creating a XML based approach and applying it to your custom Theme.

Create **anim/anim_in.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromXScale="0.0"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:fillAfter="false"
        android:startOffset="200"
        android:duration="200"
        android:pivotX = "100%"
        android:pivotY = "100%"
        />
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="50%"
        android:toYDelta="0"
        android:startOffset="200"
        android:duration="200"
        />
</set>
```

Then Create **anim/anim_out.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="0.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="0.0"
        android:fillAfter="false"
        android:duration="200"
        android:pivotX = "100%"
        android:pivotY = "100%"
        />
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="50%"
        android:duration="200"
        />
</set>
```

This animation origin pops a window or dialog fragment from right bottom corner of the screen. Modify `pivotX` and `pivotY` to change the location of the origin

Define this windows animation in your `style.xml`

```
<style name="InOut.Window" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/anim_in</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/anim_out</item>
    </style>
```

Lastly apply this animation to all the window for your custom Theme that you would have created.

```
<style ....>
...
<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/InOut.Window</item>
</style>
```

Comment: But what about round which is drawing under button after click?